# Creating a PHP array with values from a function

Tags: php, arrays

I want to create an array with x elements, where each element is created by calling a function. I'm looking for an idiomatic way to do this that minimizes state, especially mutating state, and also minimizes imperativeness.

I have working code that does this task, more specifically it creates an array with 10 elements using a function that returns a random character.

```
array_map(
    function() use ( $characters, $characterCount ) {
        return $characters[mt_rand( 0, $characterCount - 1 )];
    },
    array_fill( 0, 10, null )
)
```

When starting with this I was looking for something like the following, but did not find it:

```
array_create(
    function() {},
    10
);
```

Comment: "in more idiomatic way"?

Comment: @WizardCoder I assume op means a native function to php that does this, like the 'array_create' example

Comment: I like your approach based on `array_map()`. What's wrong with it? Appears pretty straight forward to me...

Comment: shorter to use `range(0, 9)` instead of `array_fill`

Comment: Depending on what you want to do with your array, you could use a generator instead

Comment: Generator won't work in my case since I'm passing the result into `implode`. I did consider `range` but decided against it because creating these numbers and then not using them is more misleading than what I ended up with. Also: wtf -1?!

Answer (score 3):

It is common to simply use a looping construct like:

```
$array = array();
for($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++) {
    $array[] = randomfunction();
}
```

If you want to wrap this in a function, do something like:

```
function genArray($x, $func) {
    $array = array();
    for($i = 0; $i < $x; $i++) {
        $array[] = $func();
    }
    return $array;
}
```

Then you can pass it the number of elements and which function to use!

Comment: That `genArray` function is basically what I'd like to have found in the PHP standard library. I should have mentioned this before: I prefer the code to be as functional and high level as possible. This loop approach uses mutable state and is rather imperative. So according to my criteria less nice.